# I am reading RSS link if it is not valid then throwing exception, How to handle it using PHP

Tags: php, exception, rss-reader

I am developing web application for RSS feed automation using PHP.

**Problem**
in my module i adding link of rss and store in database then those link display to the user and when they click on link they can show the data of the link.
But sometime those link is not working so throws the following runtime exceptions:

> Warning: `DOMDocument::load(http://webdesign.about.com/library
>   /z_whats_new.rss%2Ccname=Web%20design%20about)` [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: HTTP request 
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\nf\showrss.php on line 59
>
> Warning: `DOMDocument::load()` [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity 
>   `"http://webdesign.about.com/library/z_whats_new.rss%2Ccname=Web%20design%20about"` in C:\xampp\htdocs
>   \nf\showrss.php on line 59
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function `getElementsByTagName()` on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\nf\showrss.php on line 63

So how to handle this exception and display the user friendly message to user that your link is broken or not in valid rss format.
Following is the my php file to read the rss link.

**ShowRss.php**

```
<?php

$xml=$_GET["xml"];
$cname=$_GET['cname'];
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
        ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
        ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
        ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $cname;
echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link
        . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");


$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
$c=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item')->length;

for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
    $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
            ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
            ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
            ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo ("<p><h2><a href='" . $item_link
            . "'>" . $item_title . "</a></h2>

    echo ("<br>");
    echo ($item_desc ."</p>");
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOMDocument::load() returns false on failure, so you could do something like:

```
if ($xmlDoc->load($xml)) {
    // work with the XML
} else {
    // display an error message
}
```

This won't prevent the warnings from being raised, but it does allow you to handle the problem. Having the warnings could be useful to you, so you can see in your logs how often a resource you're depending on is failing.

Comment: Thanks Shanethehat. Your answer is working for me. but it is display warning as well as .. which is looking so awkward.. how to disable those warning ..? will you help me for this ? Thanks.

Comment: you can prevent the warnings from showing by turning display_errors off in your PHP config. That way they'll still be logged so you can still use them. Or if you want to display server errors but not warnings, you can set the error reporting level.